# Javascript: style.display="none" not working whereas style.display="visible" works

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, display

I am trying to create Modal structure for a product catalog.
The Modal appears whenever the user clicks on product name.

By default `modal class` has `display="none"`

The `style.display="visible";` is executed `onclick` by calling function `show(id);`

On clicking `close(X) icon` `hide(id);` is called but `style.display="none";` has no effect and modal doesn't hide.

**Please answer in simple Javascript only.**

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/abhaygc/zymkv1wq/

Code Snippet:

```js
function show(id) {
 var modal = document.getElementById(id);
 modal.style.display="block";
}
function hide(id){
 var close = document.getElementById(id);
 console.log("It's here.");
 close.style.display="none";
}
```

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
 }
.header{

  background-color: white;
  height:8%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-style: "Roboto";
  font-size: 25px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  border-bottom-color: #cccccc;
}
#clear{
  clear: both;
 }
.logo{
 margin-top: 12px;
 float: left;
 left: 0px;
 padding-right: 50px;
}
#logo:hover{
 background: transparent;
}
.links{
 display: block;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
a{
 position: relative;
 right: 0px;
 /*top: 25px;*/

 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;

 color:black;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 font-weight: 200;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
 background-color:#cccccc; 
}

.content{
 display: block;
 background-color: white;
 height: 92%;
 margin-top: 0px;
 font-family: 'Roboto';

}

#clear{
 clear: both;
}

.image{
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 300px;
 height: 150px;

 background-color: #cccccc;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

 overflow: hidden;
}

.product-1{
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 
 padding-left: 20%;
 padding-right: 0%;
 
 
 margin-top: 5%;
 
 float: left;
 left: 0px;
 width: 50%;
 overflow: hidden;

 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: none;
 border-color: black;
 border-width: 1px;
}

.product-2{
 display: block;
 position: relative;


 padding-left: 10%;
 padding-right: 0%;

 
 margin-top: 5%;
 
 float: right;

 right:0px;
 
 /*
 float: left; /*Q1
 left: 25px;
 */
 
 width: 50%;
 overflow: hidden;

 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: none;
 border-color: black;
 border-width: 1px;
}

.product-title{
 display: block;
 
 text-align: center;

 margin-top: 50px;

 color:rgb(26, 115, 232);

 font-size: 50px;
}

.modal{
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 z-index: 1;
 background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); /* Black w/ opacity */
    color:black;
    /*color:rgb(26, 115, 232);*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.modal-body{
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 left: 35%;
 top: 10%;
 font-size: 45px;
}

.close{
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 float: right;
 right: 10px;
 font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="products.css">
 <title>Products</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
   <a href="home.html"><img id="logo"src="logo.png" alt="LOGO"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="links">   
   <a href="home.html">Home</a>
   <a href="products.html">Products</a>
   <a href="login.html">Login</a>
   <a href="register.html">Register</a>
   <a href="home.html">Contact</a>
   <a href="home.html">About</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
  <div class="product-1 product" onclick="show('cns');">
   <div class="image">
     <span class="product-title">CNS</span>
   </div>
   <div id="cns" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-head">
     CNS
     <span class="close" onclick="hide('cns');">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <ol>
      <li>CNS First Product</li>
      <li>CNS Second Product</li>
      <li>CNS Third Product</li>
      <li>CNS Fourth Product</li>
     </ol>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  

  <div class="product-2 product" onclick="show('laser');">
   <div class="image">
     <span class="product-title">Laser Cut</span>
   </div>
   <div id="laser" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-head">
     Laser Cut
     <span class="close" onclick="hide('laser');">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <ol>
      <li>Laser First Product</li>
      <li>Laser Second Product</li>
      <li>Laser Third Product</li>
      <li>Laser Fourth Product</li>
     </ol>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="clear"></div>

  <div class="product-1 product" onclick="show('rubber');">
   <div class="image">
     <span class="product-title">Rubber roller</span>
   </div>
   <div id="rubber" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-head">
     Rubber roller
     <span class="close" onclick="hide('rubber');">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <ol>
      <li>Rubber First Product</li>
      <li>Rubber Second Product</li>
      <li>Rubber Third Product</li>
      <li>Rubber Fourth Product</li>
     </ol>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="product-2 product" onclick="show('fixture');">
   <div class="image">
     <span class="product-title">Fixture</span>
   </div>
   <div id="fixture" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-head">
     Fixture
     <span class="close" onclick="hide('fixture');">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <ol>
      <li>Fixture First Product</li>
      <li>Fixture Second Product</li>
      <li>Fixture Third Product</li>
      <li>Fixture Fourth Product</li>
     </ol>
    </div> 
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="products.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because of `event bubbling`.

It means that when you click on the 'X' button, the `onclick="hide('cns')"` is called and the display property is set to `none`.

Then the event bubbles up to the `product` element which in turn calls its own `onclick` method. And that causes the modal to appear again.

You could stop the event propagation by changing the current `onclick` to

```
onclick="hide('cns');event.stopPropagation()"
```

Or you could move the modal outside of the `product` element:

```
<div class="product-1 product" onclick="show('cns');">
  <div class="image">
    <span class="product-title">CNS</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cns" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-head">
    CNS
    <span class="close" onclick="hide('cns');">&times;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <ol>
      <li>CNS First Product</li>
      <li>CNS Second Product</li>
      <li>CNS Third Product</li>
      <li>CNS Fourth Product</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

To see that the display property is actually changed and then changed back, you could do the following:

```
function hide(id) {
  var close = document.getElementById(id);
  close.style.display="none";
  console.log(close.style.display);
  setTimeout(() => {console.log(close.style.display);});
}

# would print:
"none"
"block"
```

Answer (score 1):

i've updated it in fiddle, you may want to check it:
https://jsfiddle.net/zymkv1wq/28/

the key is in these lines.

```
<div class="product-1 product" onclick="show('cns');">
    <div class="image">
            <span class="product-title">CNS</span>
    </div>
    <div id="cns" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-head">
            CNS
            <span class="close" onclick="hide('cns');">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ol>
                <li>CNS First Product</li>
                <li>CNS Second Product</li>
                <li>CNS Third Product</li>
                <li>CNS Fourth Product</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

do you see? you put your `<div id="cns" class="modal">` inside this div `<div class="product-1 product" onclick="show('cns');">` which has an `onclick` callback on it.

so basically, when the `cms` modal shows up and you click the close button, you click the parent div too. which is forcing it to show again. try this, i only change the `cns` one;

```
<div class="product-1 product">
    <div class="image" onclick="show('cns');">
        <span class="product-title">CNS</span>
    </div>
    <div id="cns" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-head">
            CNS
            <span class="close" onclick="hide('cns');">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ol>
                <li>CNS First Product</li>
                <li>CNS Second Product</li>
                <li>CNS Third Product</li>
                <li>CNS Fourth Product</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

notice that the `show()` is now on class `image`.

if you want to debug your previous code, try to put `console.log('something')` inside `show()` in your JS file too. when you open ur modal, and click `close` button, you gonna see log from `show()` too